# extjs 6 combobox reload displayed value

Tags: extjs

when the store is loaded after setValue() we end up with the valueField being displayed. Once the store is loaded and we click on the dropdown, the correct item is being highlighted; but input field itself is not updated with the displayField value.

how do we refresh the input element of the combobox to reflect the selected item display field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `setValue()` in the callback function of store loading. Let assume `combo` is combobox, your code should be like that.

```
combo.store.load({
    callback: function (rec) {
       combo.setValue(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Almost. In my case, I don't control the loading of the store so even if I can attach a loaded event handler I will not have the ***value*** in that handler. Instead, there is this private function ***updateValue()*** which does update the displayed value without updating the underlying value

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that before using setValue() you use the clearValue() option. This removes the underlying value that the combobox had before. But, if you are setting the value of the combobox, the store has not been loaded yet, and it is a remote combobox, I would recommend that you first add the record to the combobox's store and then set the value to that record. Once the store is loaded again, the store will be cleared, but you will still have your first value.

```
combobox.getStore().insert(0, {
   id: 1,
   name: 'displayField'
});
combobox.setValue(1); //if your valueField is id
```

Docs for the methods mentioned above: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html

Comment: This is a good approach too. I created a plugin for the combobox that adds the ability the set value and its display field. I check for loaded state before injecting.